# Objects getting deleted after a loop runs once

Tags: excel, vba

my code is structured like this

```
Set rng1 = some range
Set rng2 = some range
For Each cell1 In rng1
    For Each cell2 In rng2
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = some workbook
        wb.Worksheets("Setup").Cells(1, 1).Value = cell1
        wb.Worksheets("Setup").Cells(1, 2).Value = cell2
        Application.Run some function
    Next cell2
Next cell1
```

after the inner loop executes once rng1 and rng2 get destroyed and all their attributes become `<Object Required>`. why is that happening?

Comment: Try the `Dim` and `Set` lines outside of the loop.

Comment: @braX set is outside the loop. dim is unrelated to rng.

Comment: `Application.Run some function` Share the code for `some function`

Comment: Set is most definitely in the loop..... you have two `For Each` statements and the `Dim` & `Set` are after those lines and before the `Next` lines.  Moving the Set outside the loop also requires moving the Dim outside the loop as you can't use a variable until you've defined it... unless you haven't got `Option Explicit` in which case the code just makes it up as you go along anyway (although it probably won't like you trying to Dim a variable after you've already Set it).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = some workbook
Set rng1 = some range
Set rng2 = some range
For Each cell1 In rng1
    For Each cell2 In rng2
        wb.Worksheets("Setup").Cells(1, 1).Value = cell1
        wb.Worksheets("Setup").Cells(1, 2).Value = cell2
        Application.Run some function
    Next cell2
Next cell1
```

Implying that the `function` does not inflict other problems.